# Python: .strip() method is not working as expected

Tags: python, string, strip

I have two strings:

```
my_str_1 = '200327_elb_72_ch_1429.csv'
my_str_2 = '200327_elb_10_ch_1429.csv'
```

When I call `.strip()` method on both of them I get results like this:

```
>>> print(my_str_1.strip('200327_elb_'))
'ch_1429.csv'
>>> print(my_str_2.strip('200327_elb_'))
'10_ch_1429.csv'
```

I expected result of `print(my_str_1.strip('200327_elb_'))` to be `'72_ch_1429.csv'`. Why isn't it that case? Why these two result aren't consistent? What am I missing?

Comment: Strip removes characters, not strings.

Comment: In the first case, `72_` is among the chars to be removed, so you end up with `'ch_1429.csv'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> [...] The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. [...] The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped [...]

This method removes all specified characters that appear at the left or right end of the original string, till on character is reached that is not specified; it does not just remove leading/trailing substrings, it takes each character individually.

Clarifying example (from `Jon Clements` comment); note that the characters `a` from the middle are NOT removed:

```
>>> 'aa3aa3aa'.strip('a')
'3aa3'
>>> 'a4a3aa3a5a'.strip('a54')
'3aa3'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for an explanation.

Comment: Umm... *This method removes all specified characters that appear anywhere in the original string* - that's slightly misleading... it'll only remove any consecutive leading/trailing characters that are present - it won't remove characters from *anywhere* eg: `'aaaeaeaaa'.strip('a')` will only remove the leading/trailing 'a's and not the one in the middle... but `'aaaefaeaaa'.strip('ae')` will indeed just leave you with 'f'